# Rail travel between Azerbaijan and Georgia

Tags: trains, georgia-country, tbilisi, azerbaijan

I'm looking for any advice please. I'm travelling around Azerbaijan this August and need to work out the best way to get from Ganja in Azerbaijan to Tbilisi in Georgia. I've tried to find train information but the online info I've found has been useless.

Comment: You will want to read: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7287/how-to-get-from-sheki-to-tbilisi

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest going back to the source [Azerbaijan Railways LTD](http://railway.gov.az/index/en/4-passengers/timetable/local) timetable for local trains:

There is a daily train from Baku to Tbilisi daily leaving Baku @20:30 local time.  There is also an express train from Ganja to Baku leaving every other day (English version is incorrect) @9:00.  I can't find information about the stops of the fast train to Tbilisi.

If you area looking for other options you can look at the question that @MastaBaba linked:

- [How to get from Sheki to Tbilisi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7287/how-to-get-from-sheki-to-tbilisi)

as well as:

- [Where can I find details of the bus between Tbilisi Georgia and Baku Azerbaijan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/where-can-i-find-details-of-the-bus-between-tbilisi-georgia-and-baku-azerbaijan?rq=1)

**ADDTIONAL INFO**

Found a site in Russian which states that train [Tbilisi-Baku](http://travelgeorgia.ru/18) does stop overnight in Gandja.